# PHP POST 403 error forbidden when a form field contains "and 1"

Tags: php, azure, http-status-code-403

I have a really weird error. I am performing an insert of data using the query below.

Every input entered into the form works correctly unless the phrase (without the double quotes) "and 1" is entered within a form field. I have tried "and 56", "and 42" both fail. Entering "andd 10" works fine.

A 403 error appears anytime an and followed by a number is entered. It does not matter if it's at the beginning, middle, or end of a sentence. I am connecting to an SQL database in Azure. The variable causing the issue is $value. This issue is occurring in all browsers.

```
    $cleanInput = htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $value = htmlentities( $cleanInput, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');   

    $query = "INSERT INTO [researchdb].[dbo].[tbl_Research_Intake_Admin_Forms_Input_Data] ";    
    $query .="(form_token,input_id,input_data,data_submission_num, input_sort_order) ";
    $query .="VALUES(?,?,CAST(? as as nvarchar(max)),?,?) ";

    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $query);
    $success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($frmToken,$inputId,$value,$submissionNumber, $inputSortOrder));
```

Comment: This sounds like a protection against SQL injection in the webserver.

Comment: `AND 1=1` is often part of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is there a work around for this. If I enter the phrase "there was a witch and 400 flying monkeys", I get a 403 error

Comment: Disable the server setting that's doing this.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.